# How to upload java server to remote server?

Tags: mysql, database, jakarta-ee, server-side

Hello I've created an android application, with server-side code.
So I have my android app (Client) Server-side code(Server) and database (mysql workbench).
I created my server side in Java J2EE and its running on localhost. 
Everything works just fine. 
I need help in how to upload my server and database to remote server so everyone can access from everywhere. - Not just from my local lan.
thank for the help

Comment: This question is very broad to answer here.

Comment: can you try please its very importent

Comment: which server do you have ?

Comment: im using tomcat 7, http server

Answer (score 0):

you have to buy a space in public server(or public ip) install tomcat and mysql there,deploy your application(.war file) in tomcat and import you db in mysql you have installed.

Some servers already have tomcat and mysql running. Google it for the vendors.

Try buying a shared server in the starting.

You can go for amazon s3 or can have cPanel from any linux server available in market.

Comment: thanks, can you give me some cPanel that already have tomcat and mysql, there is free public servers ?

Comment: Something that supports java ?